# What's wrong with my Paypal IPN? It works on Sandbox but not live

Tags: paypal

so I've been trying to set up Paypal IPN, and been trying tonnes of different solutions to get my IPN to validate. For some reason, it works fine when I'm using Sanbox paypal, but as soon as I try to use the live version, nothing happens. No error logs, no IPN logs, nothing. I'm just lost.

I was wondering if any new eyes would spot the problem. Here's my paypal.php class:

```
    <?php

session_start();
$base = "/var/www/html/";
include("db.php");
require_once('paypal.class.php');  // include the class file
$p = new paypal_class;             // initiate an instance of the class
//$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';   // testing paypal url
$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';     // paypal url

// setup a variable for this script (ie: 'http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal.php')
$this_script = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if there is not action variable, set the default action of 'process'
if (empty($_GET['action'])) $_GET['action'] = 'process';  

if (empty($_GET['amm'])) $_GET['amm'] = '1';

$EMAIL = 'emailaddresshere';


switch ($_GET['action']) {

   case 'process':      // Process and order...

if (empty($_GET['prod'])){
header("Location: confirm-product.php");        //Was donate.php (but no file for that, so might be confirm-product)
 exit;
}

if (empty($_GET['username'])){
if($_GET['action'] = 'process'){
header("Location: confirm-product.php");            // was donate.php as well
 exit;
}
} 
      //if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
      //    header("Location: login.php");
      //    exit;
      //}

      //include("include.php");
//die("donation is temporarily disabled!");

      // There should be no output at this point.  To process the POST data,
      // the submit_paypal_post() function will output all the HTML tags which
      // contains a FORM which is submited instantaneously using the BODY onload
      // attribute.  In other words, don't echo or printf anything when you're
      // going to be calling the submit_paypal_post() function.

      // This is where you would have your form validation  and all that jazz.
      // You would take your POST vars and load them into the class like below,
      // only using the POST values instead of constant string expressions.

      // For example, after ensureing all the POST variables from your custom
      // order form are valid, you might have:
      //
      // $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
      // $p->add_field('last_name', $_POST['last_name']);

    $price = '10.00';
        if($_GET['prod'] == 1)
            $price = '10.00';
        if($_GET['prod'] == 2)
            $price = '45.00';
        if($_GET['prod'] == 3)
            $price = '80.00';
        if($_GET['prod'] == 4)
            $price = '300.00';
        if($_GET['prod'] == 5)          //remove/change prod 5 after testing
            $price = '0.01';

    $name = '1K Donator Points';
        if ($_GET['prod'] == 1)
            $name = '1K Donator Points';
        if ($_GET['prod'] == 2)
            $name = '5K Donator Points';
        if ($_GET['prod'] == 3)
            $name = '10K Donator Points';
        if ($_GET['prod'] == 4)
            $name = '50K Donator Points';
        if ($_GET['prod'] == 5)
            $name = 'Testing Payment';
      $p->add_field('custom', $_GET['username']);
      $p->add_field('business', $EMAIL);
      $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success');
      $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
      $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
      $p->add_field('item_name', ''.$name);
      $p->add_field('item_number', $_GET['prod']);
      $p->add_field('currency_code', 'USD');
      $p->add_field('amount', $price);
      //$p->add_field('quantity', $_GET['amm']);
      $p->add_field('lc', 'GB');
      $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
 //     $p->dump_fields();      // for debugging, output a table of all the fields
      break;

   case 'success':      // Order was successful...

      // This is where you would probably want to thank the user for their order
      // or what have you.  The order information at this point is in POST
      // variables.  However, you don't want to "process" the order until you
      // get validation from the IPN.  That's where you would have the code to
      // email an admin, update the database with payment status, activate a
      // membership, etc.  

      //include("include.php");
      echo "<h2>Donation Successful</h2><p>Your payment has been completed.</p>";
      // You could also simply re-direct them to another page, or your own
      // order status page which presents the user with the status of their
      // order based on a database (which can be modified with the IPN code
      // below).
      break;

   case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...

      // The order was canceled before being completed.
      //include("include.php");
      echo "<h2>Payment Cancelled</h2><p>Your payment was cancelled.</p>";

      break;

   case 'ipn':          // Paypal is calling page for IPN validation...

      // It's important to remember that paypal calling this script.  There
      // is no output here.  This is where you validate the IPN data and if it's
      // valid, update your database to signify that the user has payed.  If
      // you try and use an echo or printf function here it's not going to do you
      // a bit of good.  This is on the "backend".  That is why, by default, the
      // class logs all IPN data to a text file.
      if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
        error_log("Made it to validating IPN", 3, "myerrors.log");

         // Payment has been recieved and IPN is verified.  This is where you
         // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
         // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
         // etc.  You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.

         // Check the paypal documentation for specifics on what information
         // is available in the IPN POST variables.  Basically, all the POST vars
         // which paypal sends, which we send back for validation, are now stored
         // in the ipn_data() array.

         if($p->ipn_data["payment_status"] != "Completed") die();

         error_log("Payment Status = Completed, if this message shows - ", 3, "myerrors.log");

         if($p->ipn_data["mc_gross"] > 0 && strcmp ($p->ipn_data["business"],$EMAIL) == 0) {
            error_log("Blah blah blah 33", 3, "myerrors.log");
             $user = $p->ipn_data["custom"];
             $date = $p->ipn_data["payment_date"];
             $prodid = $p->ipn_data["item_number"];
             $amount = $p->ipn_data["mc_gross"];
             $amountTickets = 1;

             $user = str_replace("-", "_", $user);
             $user = str_replace(" ", "_", $user);
             $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user);
             $prodid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $prodid);
             $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $amount);
             $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "name", "pass", "db");
             if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        //      error_log("Connection Failed to Database", 3, "myerrors.log");
            } 
                $query = "INSERT INTO donation (username, time, productid, price, tickets) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$date."', '".$prodid."', '".$amount."', '".$amountTickets."');";
                $mysqli->query($query);
                //
             error_log("Passed through MySql Table insertion lines.", 3, "myerrors.log");
         }
         error_log("  -   Finished validating IPN process.", 3, "myerrors.log");
      }
      break;
 }    

?>
```

And here's my paypal.class.php class

```
    <?php
/*******************************************************************************
 *                      PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class
 *******************************************************************************
 *      Author:     Micah Carrick
 *      Email:      email@micahcarrick.com
 *      Website:    http://www.micahcarrick.com
 *
 *      File:       paypal.class.php
 *      Version:    1.3.0
 *      Copyright:  (c) 2005 - Micah Carrick
 *                  You are free to use, distribute, and modify this software
 *                  under the terms of the GNU General Public License.  See the
 *                  included license.txt file.
 * 
 *******************************************************************************
*/

class paypal_class {

   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal  
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal

    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';


   function paypal_class() {

      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

      $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';          //real one
   //   $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';        //testing one

      $this->last_error = '';

      $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
      $this->ipn_log = true;
      $this->ipn_response = '';

      // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
      // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
      // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick');

   }

   public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

   function add_field($field, $value) {

      // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be
      // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the
      // array, it will be overwritten.

      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {

      // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
      // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the
      // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
      // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So
      // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
      // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
      // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

      // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
      // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
      // is redirected to paypal.

      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
      echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
      echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
      }
      echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
      echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";

      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";

   }

   function validate_ipn() {

      // parse the paypal URL
 //     $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);  
        error_log("  - Parsed URL.", 3, "myerrors.log");    //remove after

      // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
      // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
      // script.
      $post_string = '';   //old
    //  $post_string="cmd=_notify-validate";        //new
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) {
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
         $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&';        //old
    //  $post_string .= '&' . $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)); //new
      }
      $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      error_log("  - Into ValidatingIPN, Line 187.", 3, "myerrors.log");    //remove after

      // open the connection to paypal
    //  $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'], 443, $errnum, $errstr, 30);    //old real one
 //     $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errnum, $errstr, 30); //try this
 //     $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);  //try this
    //  $fp = fsockopen('https://www.paypal.com', 443, $errnum, $errstr, 30);
 //     $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);      //testing one

    /*  if ($url_parsed['scheme'] == 'https') {
            $url_parsed['port'] = 443;
            $ssl = 'ssl://';
        } else {
            $url_parsed['port'] = 80;
            $ssl = '';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($ssl.$url_parsed['host'], $url_parsed['port'], $errnum, $errstr, 30); */

                    //Real One v2
            $uri = 'ssl://www.paypal.com';
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

      if(!$fp) {
          throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
      }

         // Post the data back to paypal
    //     fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");       //old
    /*     fputs($fp, "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n");
         fputs($fp, "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n");            //sandbox  - www.sandbox.paypal.com
         fputs($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
         fputs($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n");
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); */

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";          //real - www.paypal.com
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$post_string."\r\n\r\n");

         error_log("  - Connected to paypal connection. Posted Data to paypal.", 3, "myerrors.log");    //remove after

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) {
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);        //old
         }

         fclose($fp); // close connection


    //  if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {    //old
      if (preg_match("VERIFIED", $this->ipn_response)) {    //new       ~VERIFIED~i for sandbox

         // Valid IPN transaction.
         error_log("  - Valid IPN Transaction.", 3, "myerrors.log");    //remove after
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;      

      } else {

         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         error_log("  - IPN Validation Failed", 3, "myerrors.log"); //remove after
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);      //Default: false  
         return false;

      }

   }

   function log_ipn_results($success) {

      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - ';

      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }

      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {

      // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
      // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
      // add_field() function.

      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
           <tr>
              <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
              <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
           </tr>";

      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }

      echo "</table><br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have IPN enabled in the live account profile?  Have you checked the IPN History in the live account to see what it's showing?

Comment: @AndrewAngell Thanks for the reply - I have enabled IPN on paypal, yes. The problem is that the IPN History shows it's retrying every payment processed, so that's where the problem is. I've tried all sorts!

Comment: Have you checked your web server logs?  You should be able to lookup the hits to your IPN script and see the error that is happening when it's hit.

Comment: @AndrewAngell no error logs show I just have the ipn results log which shows verified ipn

Comment: Your web server has to have error logs.  I'm not talking about anything you built into the script, but Apache or IIS or whatever web server you're using would be logging for any failed request.  You should be able to see the same info you would see in the browser if you had run it there.